# Why is the output of "complex(20+10j,5+5j),complex(10+10j,5+5j)" as "(15+15j),(5+15j)" and explain with more examples?

Tags: python, spyder

Why is output of (31+5j.real) as 31.0 and (31+5j.imag) as 36.0?
Why is output of (42.real) as 42 and (42.imag) as 42?
Why is output of (complex(20+10j,5+5j)) as ((15+15j) and (complex(10+10j,5+5j)) as (5+15j)?

I would like to know the answer as I am confused as how complex relation functions work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not a math site

Comment: You should go and learn about _complex numbers_.

Comment: `(42.imag)` is a SyntaxError, not 42.

Comment: not the right site

Comment: It looks to me like the misunderstandings here are about Python, not about complex numbers, so it's appropriate to ask here rather than on a math site.

Answer (score 1):

For `31+5j.real` and `31+5j.imag`, you're adding `31` and the real or imaginary part of `5j`.

The real and imaginary parts of `5j` are `0.0` and `5.0` respectively, so you get `31.0` or `36.0`.

You likely meant `(31+5j).real` and `(31+5j).imag`, to take the real or imaginary parts of `31+5j` instead.

---

`42.real` and `42.imag` are both invalid syntax. `42.imag` does not give `42`. If what you really tested was `42+0j.real` and `42+0j.imag`, then see above.

---

`complex(a, b)` evaluates to `a+b*1j`, even if `a` or `b` already have imaginary parts. This is kind of weird, but it explains why you're seeing the output you did for `complex(20+10j,5+5j)` and `complex(10+10j,5+5j)`. (The implementation isn't quite `a+b*1j`, which can matter for NaNs and signed zeros, but for most purposes, it's the same.)